# Node Mobility in Unetstack V 3.1.0

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet, unetstack

I am trying to simulate a node moving with circular trajectory, which is receiving data from 4 stationary nodes. The simulation is working fine on the older version (1.6), however it is not working on 3.1.0. There is no error and the simulation is being completed, however no packets are being transmitted or received. Is there any major differences between these two versions in terms of syntax or models, due to which no packet transmission is taking place? The codes were written for the older version.

'''

```
if(addr==31)
     {       
        add new WakerBehavior(2200, {
             phy[1].powerLevel = -35.dB;    // must be non- positive
             phy[2].powerLevel = -35.dB;
             phy << new ClearReq()
             phy << new DatagramReq(to: 21 ,data : neighbouraddr1 , protocol:cluster_protocol)  
             println "data sent by 31 to 21"
        })
```

'''

This is the code snippet for one of the stationary nodes. Similarly, we have codes for the other 3 nodes.

'''

```
void processMessage(Message msg) {
      if(addr == 21)
      {
          
          if (msg instanceof DatagramNtf && msg.protocol == cluster_protocol  && (  msg.from == 31 || msg.from == 32 || msg.from == 33  || msg.from == 34 || msg.from == 35) )      //notfication recieved 
          {
            println "message processed in address:"+addr 
              println "DATA Received by ${addr} from ${msg.from}, DATA VALUE is ${msg.data}"
              collectB.addAll(msg.data)
              println "now total value is ${collectB}"
          }
      }
```

'''

We used this to consolidate the messages received at node B.

Comment: The code snippets look OK to me as part of an agent code (not simulation DSL). Where and how they are integrated in a simulation script may have a bearing on how they work. Perhaps you can post or provide a link to your simulation script?